# Sigma sums problem

Tags: summation

Could you please help me with the below result?

How do we get from here

$(1+2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\rho^j)π_0=1$

To here

$π_0=(1-\rho)/(1+\rho)$

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\lvert \rho \rvert < 1$, then you can sum the GP : $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^\infty \rho^j = \dfrac{\rho}{1-\rho}$

Comment: Many thanks for the help! I understand it now.

Comment: Either you are missing an $-1$ on the right side or the sum has to start with $j=0$

Comment: Sorry, I misread you right side as $\frac{1}{1-\rho}$.